# Calling Oracle PL/SQL PLS-00201: identifier '001' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-06550

I am trying to call a PL/SQL script with the following header:

PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETQUOTE(i_QUOTEID IN HR.QUOTEID,
                                     o_QUOTE OUT HR.QUOTE)
```

Execute command:

```
DECLARE c VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

  HR.GETQUOTE("001", c);

END;
/
```

Error:

```
declare
c varchar2(100);
begin
HR.GETQUOTE("001", c);
end;

ORA-06550: line 4, column 29:
PLS-00201: identifier '001' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong types of quotes.  If you want `001` to be string literal, you need to use single quotes.

Try this:

```
SELECT '001' FROM dual;

SELECT "001" FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the single quotes:

then

check that the first value is a string not a number inside the procedure.
you may also try to_number('001') as the argument

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
declare c varchar2(100);

begin    
  hr.getquote('001', c);    
end;    
/
```

In pl/sql single quotes must be used for strings.

Comment: No, when using the single quotes, i am having a PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETQUOTE'.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the GETQUOTE procedure. Is it possible to see it's code?

Comment: Also I am not sure about HR.QUOTEID type.Do you mean HR.QUOTEID%type? What is the actually type of HR.QUOTEID?